# creating high secured encrypted id to website url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Controller:

```
function verifyuser()
{
    $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
    //print_r($uri);
    if( isset( $uri['id'] ) && $uri['id'] != '' )

            {
            $where = array();
                $where['roll_number'] = $uri['id']; 
$this->data['verification'] = $this->admin_model->verify($where);


        }
        else
        {
        $this->data['verification'] = array();

        }
    $this->data['content'] = 'admin/verification';
    $this->view($this->data);   
}
```

MODEL:

```
function verify($where='')

{
  $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from( $this->db->dbprefix('members') );
if( !(empty( $where )) )
$this->db->where( $where );


$result = $this->db->get();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $result->result();

}
```

www.example.com/user/admin/verify/**345**
 to
www.example.com/user/admin/verify/**hgf_877%%%_oi**

like this.

Comment: A more secured way would be using a username/password combination & authenticate user. If you still want to implement it your way then just generate a random word, encrypt it using bcrypt or sha1 & use it in urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any of encoding's defined in [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php) Manual for your security purposes. But i prefer base64_encode and base64_decode. Which i am using my application for encoding comples strings.

```
<?php
$temp = 345;
$res = base64_encode($temp);
echo $res;echo "<br>";
$result = base64_decode($res);
echo $result;
?>
```

You can find small example in this [link](http://eval.in/9618) also.